# Displot dips between whole numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a density curve with seaborn using age of vehicles.
My density curve has dips between the whole numbers while my age values are all whole number.
Can't seem to find anything related to this issue so I thought I would try my luck here, any input is appreciated.
My fix currently is just using a histogram with a larger bin but would like to get this working with a density plot.

Thanks!

[image: My KDE]

Comment: Please create a [reprex].  Include sample data and the code *as text*, not just a screenshot.

Comment: In this case the ages are probably discrete, not continues, which is why the `kde` appears to be multimodal. As such, a `kde` plot is not a valid visualization. [Kernel Density Estimation for a Discrete Variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/526120/257240) & [Kernel density estimation and discrete values](https://aakinshin.net/posts/kde-discrete/)

Comment: Set `bw_adjust` to a suitable value > 1. See the notes and examples in the kdeplot docs for more.

Comment: That should be **continuous**, not _continues_

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In [**`seaborn.displot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) you are passing the `kind = 'kde'` parameter, in order to get a continuous corve. However, this parameter triggers the [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) computation, which compute values for all number, included non integers ones.
Instead, you need to tune [**`seaborn.histplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) in order to get a continuous step curve with `element` and `fill` parameters (I create a fake dataframe just to draw a plot, since you didn't provide your data):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': np.random.poisson(lam = 4, size = N)})
df['age'] = df['age'] + 1


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (8, 4))

sns.histplot(ax = ax[0], data = df, bins = np.arange(0.5, df['age'].max() + 1, 1))
sns.histplot(ax = ax[1], data = df, bins = np.arange(0.5, df['age'].max() + 1, 1), element = 'step', fill = False)

ax[0].set_xticks(range(1, 14))
ax[1].set_xticks(range(1, 14))

plt.show()
```

[image]

As a comparison, here the [**`seaborn.displot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) on the same dataframe, passing `kind = 'kde'` parameter:

[image]

Comment: What about `sns.displot(data=df, x='age', kind='kde', bw_method=0.3)`?

Comment: For the `histplot`, using `discrete=True` instead of `binwidth=1` would put the bins nicely centered around the discrete values.  Compare `sns.histplot(data=np.random.randint(0, 15, 10000), binwidth=1)` to `sns.histplot(data=np.random.randint(0, 15, 10000), discrete=True)`  and you'll notice the last bin will be wrong for `binwidth=1`.

Comment: `bw_method=0.3` parameter generates a nice smooth curve but, since data values are only integers, I interpret the questioner's request as wanting to draw a discrete line, contant for each `age` value, so I think a stair plot may be the optimal choice

Comment: Nice the suggestion to use `discrete=True` which fit in a more correct way data meaning. However `seaborn` reports `ValueError: 'element' must be 'bars' when 'discrete' is True`, so I cannot use `discrete=True` parameter in conjunction with `element = 'step'`

Comment: You could use `data = np.random.randint(0, 15, 10000); sns.histplot(data=data, bins=np.arange(-0.5, data.max() + 1, 1), element='step', fill=False)` instead of the wrong last bin of  `sns.histplot(data=np.random.randint(0, 15, 10000), binwidth=1, element='step', fill=False)`.

Comment: You are perfectly right. Thank for your preciuos suggestions